# WebAPI: using async methods in business logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

The aim is to make controller that uses async method in my custom service.

Controller:

```
[Route("api/data/summary")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var result = await DataService.GetDataObjects();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Service:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<DataObject>> GetDataObjects()
{
    var apiKey = "some-api-key";
    var path = "path-to-external-service";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var dataToProcess = // some data object

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(path);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", dataToProcess);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var result = MakeEntities(content); // some logic

        return result;
    }
}
```

But I came across with the problem that controller's action returns empty result before service actually finished processing data.

Could you please advice how to implement it correctly?

Comment: Looking at code does not look like controller action can return result before service finished processing data. Can you debug the service and find out what is the expected output.

Comment: What versdion of ASP .NET web api do yo use? Make sure you get no Exception during execution of `GetDataObjects`.

Comment: You are returning always Ok, are you sure that the application is not rising Exceptions?

Comment: Do you have any async function calls inside `MakeEntities(content)`?
if it so, and you don't wait them with await keywords, then inside `result` variable will be null and it will be passed to OK result

Comment: @AndreyIschencko, there is no async stuff inside MakeEntities, just plain materializing from json string to object

Comment: @Pavel, using web api 2.0

Comment: There was exception within "MakeEntities" method...Now it works. Sorry for my inattention, and thanks for help)

Comment: Well, you can at least mark someone's answer as a useful one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK and controller doesn't seem to return a value before `GetDataObjects` returns value.

Except for the situations below:

1. `MakeEntities` uses some asynchronous operation and you don't await it inside MakeEntities. So `MakeEntities` return task.
2. Exception rises while your code is running. Make sure `GetDataObjects` and `MakeEntities` code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The aim is to make controller that uses async method in my custom service.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/data/summary")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var result = await DataService.GetDataObjects().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Service:

```
public static async Task<ResponseEntity> GetDataObjects()
{
    ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity();
    var apiKey = "some-api-key";
    var path = "path-to-external-service";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var dataToProcess = // some data object    
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(path);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));    
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", dataToProcess).ConfigureAwait(false);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);    
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseEntity>(responseString);

        return response;
    }
}
```